# Jquery POST 400 Bad request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, http-status-code-400

Can someone help me with this 400 bad request I'm getting?
Here is my code:

```
saveBttn.click(function() {        
        var expireDate = $('#expire_date_picker').val();
        var newStatus = $('#User_email').val();
        if (expireDate.length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'updateCases/',            
                data: {expireDate: expireDate, newStatus: newStatus },                
                type: 'POST',                
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success!!");
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Its not even getting to the desired action...

Comment: You are making an AJAX call to a folder?

Comment: Is it the right url ?

Comment: check the controller and action is proper or not

Comment: Generally **Bad Request** comes when when you miss parameters. Please check whether you are sending all the parameters needed.

Comment: @Shubham or if you might send some element instead of value.

Comment: @SherinJose you were right, it was an url problem,

Answer (score 1):

Set your data type and correct your parameters.

```
saveBttn.click(function() {        
        var expireDate = $('#expire_date_picker').val();
        var newStatus = $('#User_email').val();
        if (expireDate.length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: 'updateCases/',            
                data: {'expireDate': expireDate,'newStatus' : newStatus },                
                type: 'POST',                
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success!!");
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter names in method must be same  'expireDate' and 'newStatus' respectively.If this is true,there should be problem in  your url parameter

Comment: Hi have them just like that.

Answer (score 1):

try this

specify url with prefix '/'

```
     $.ajax({
            url: '/updateCases',            
            data: {expireDate: expireDate, newStatus: newStatus },                
            type: 'POST',                
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success!!");
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```